Ansible cron job is not working for two tasks
Below is the main.yml
---
# your_playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  become_method: sudo
  roles:
    - include_role:
      name: cron_job
      vars:
        cron_jobs:
          - script_path: "/export/storage_mount.sh"
            script_arguments: "action"
          - script_path: "/export/service_status.sh"
            script_arguments: ""

cron role:
---
- name: Create cron job
  ansible.builtin.cron:
    name: "Run script every 5 minutes"
    minute: "5"
    job: "/bin/bash {{ item.script_path }} {{ item.script_arguments }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ cron_jobs }}"

Role running output:
changed: [host01] => (item={'script_path': '/export/apps/scripts/storage_mount.sh', 'script_arguments': 'action'})
changed: [host01] => (item={'script_path': '/export/apps/scripts/service_status.sh', 'script_arguments': ''})

It only creates one entry not two entries in crontab
#Ansible: Run script every 5 minutes
5 * * * * /bin/bash /export/service_status.sh 

How to fix this?

Probably because you've used the same name: "Run script every 5 minutes". You could try with name: "Job {{ ansible_loop.index }} - Run script every 5 minutes" from Extended loop variables. Or just name: "Run {{ item.script_path | basename }} every 5 minutes".


How to loop on Ansible cron module?

This is probably because you've used the same parameter name: "Run script every 5 minutes". This will make the same entry twice whereby the second run wins.
You could

either try with name: "Job {{ ansible_loop.index }} - Run script every 5 minutes" from Extended loop variables
or just name: "Run {{ item.script_path | basename }} every 5 minutes" with basename filter – get a path’s base name

